# PkgConfig - package 'linux' not found

Tags: linux, build, cmake, packaging, pkg-config

I wasnt't sure whether to put it on StackOverflow or AskUbuntu, but decided to post it here.
I have a problem building my app. I'm using CMake for building and one of the PkgConfig packages it depends on is `linux`. And when I'm trying to build it, it shows this error:

```
--   package 'linux' not found
```

When I'm removing the `linux` package from the dependencies, it complains about some Vala libraries isn't found. And the only way it is working is removing `linux` from the dependencies, then running `cmake`, then putting it to the dependencies again, then running `make`, then everything works fine (I don't know why).

I suppose I don't have some Ubuntu package installed and I don't have `linux*.pc` file, but I can't figure out what to do with it.
Can you help me with it?

UPD: Here is part of my `CMakeFiles.txt` file that raises the error:

```
find_package (PkgConfig)
message(STATUS "PKG_CONFIG_PATH: \"" ${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}\")

set (CORE_PKG
  linux
  gstreamer-1.0
  gtk+-3.0
  glib-2.0>=2.32
  gio-2.0
  json-glib-1.0
  webkit2gtk-4.0>=2.6.1
  libxml-2.0
  gdk-x11-3.0
  gstreamer-video-1.0
  libnotify
  libsoup-2.4
  gee-0.8
)

pkg_check_modules (CORE_DEPS REQUIRED ${CORE_PKG})
```

Comment: You have to show us the part of your cmake config files that gives you this error, along with other relevant info - such as what you intended to do, and what you expect to happen (e.g. why are you trying to use PkgConfig to look for a "linux" package ?) and how you invoke cmake in case you do anything special.

Comment: @nos added this to question

Comment: @nos I was trying to add this library: https://github.com/PerfectCarl/vala-stacktrace to my app, and it has `linux` in dependencies. Isn't it using `pkg-config` to find it? I'm not sure about it.

Comment: No, at first glance I can't see that thing trying to find a linux package with pkg-config, and I'm pretty sure there's nothing that would provide it. It seems that vala package is built using set of cmake macros intended to make life "easier"... , and there's notes about the "linux" package [here](https://github.com/PerfectCarl/elementary.cmake/blob/master/cmake/Elementary.cmake#L528)

Comment: @nos I tried to remove `linux` from the deps and instead add `--pkg linux` to the `valac` arguments, it seems like it is working now. Thanks tor the tips! )